# c: find the connection (common node) between two simple lists

Tags: c, list

I'm working for an exercise in C where I have to find out if there is a connection between two lists (pointer at the same node).

I'm trying to do this with two `for` loops and comparing the pointers (or I think so...):

- `newList()`: creates a simple connected list.
- `findsize()`: returns the number of nodes.
- `synthesi()`: prints to console the position of common node and return a pointer at the node if exists.

Also the compiler "complains" about `tmp = tmp->next` and occasionally about `cur = cur->next` because of the last `next` pointer of `list` which is null (as it supposed to be in a simple list).

```
struct list{
    int num;
    struct list *next;
};

struct list* synthesi(struct list*, struct list*);
int findSize(struct list*);
struct list* newList();

void main()
{
    struct list *hd1, *hd2, *syn;
    int sizeofhd1, sizeofhd2;

    hd1 = newList();
    hd2 = newList();

    /*do{                                   test
        printf("list1: %d\n", hd1->num);
        printf("list1: %d\n", hd2->num);
        hd1 = hd1->next;
        hd2 = hd2->next;
    } while (hd2!=NULL);
    */
    sizeofhd1 = findSize(hd1);
    sizeofhd2 = findSize(hd2);

    //printf("list1: %d\n", sizeofhd1);     test
    //printf("list2: %d\n", sizeofhd2);

    syn = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    syn = synthesi(hd1, hd2);

    printf("synthesi: %d\n", syn->num);
}

int findSize(struct list *head)
{
    struct list *cur;
    int flag = 0;

    cur = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    cur = head;
    do
    {
        flag++;
        cur = cur->next;
    }while (cur!=NULL);
    free(cur);
    return flag;
}

struct list* synthesi(struct list *head1, struct list *head2)
{
    int i,j, pos, sizeofhd1, sizeofhd2;
    struct list *tmp;
    tmp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    sizeofhd1=findSize(head1);
    sizeofhd2 = findSize(head1);

    for (i = 0; i < sizeofhd1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sizeofhd2; j++)
        {
            if (head1->next == tmp)
            {
                pos = i + i;
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        head1 = head1->next;
        tmp = head2;

    }
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        puts("no connection!\n");
        return (struct list*)NULL;
    }
    else{
        puts("found at position: ");
        printf("%d\n", pos);
        return head1->next;
    }
}

struct list* newList()
{
    struct list *mylist, *hd;
    int i;
    hd = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    mylist = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    mylist->num = 7;
    mylist->next = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    hd = mylist;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mylist->next = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        mylist->next->num = i + 1;
        mylist = mylist->next;
        mylist->next = (struct list*)NULL;
    }
    return hd;
}
```

Comment: Guys, can you *please* stop tagging things that are clearly C with [tag:c++]? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `list` struct is actually not a list but a node from a list. I would rename that to `node` and create a `list` struct with variables  `head` and `cur` and take it from there.

Comment: If too lists have a common node, all next nodes are in both lists too? Isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it is the compiler 'occasionally' complaining. I am betting the program once compiled and linked does not always work:

`findsize` appears to have some bugs. First you allocate a new list, then you overwrite the newly allocated list, then at the end of the routine you free it, freeing the list you are trying to find the size of. Try this:

```
int findSize(struct list *node)
{
    int num = 0;
    for (; node ; node=node->next)
        num++;
    return num;
}
```

In `synthesi` you are again allocating a list item for no particular reason. All you need to do is step through one list, and step through the other inside it. If the idea is to find an item on both lists (i.e. where `num` is the same), something like:

```
struct list *
findcommonnumber (struct list *lista, struct list *listb)
{
    struct list *a;
    struct list *b;
    for (a=lista; a; a=a->next)
    {
        for (b=listb; b; b=b->next)
        {
            if (a->num == b->num)
            {
                printf ("Found %d at %p and %p\n", a->num, a, b);
                return a;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This is assuming you are actually trying to find an item with the same number on both lists, since the same actual item should not be on two lists (think about it).

Also your `list` structure appears to be a list item structure and should probably be so called.

Comment: thx for your time and answer!
no... we are searching for the common node (that's why i compare pointers in if) not the 'common' integer!
yeah you are right about list/node thing... :)